# How to define a property to avoid: Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Y'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a paginated list of devices such as name, serial and so on coming from the Restful API.
I used get method of ***Axios*** in order to fetch the list.
Take a look at the following component in **Reactjs**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export interface Props{
  url: string;
}
export interface State{
  devices: string[];
  currentUrl: string;
}
class Devices extends React.Component<Props, State>{
    constructor(props: Props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {devices: [], currentUrl: props.url};
      console.log('first log',this.state);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(this.state.currentUrl)
        .then(({data}) =>{
          console.log('Joye Data', data);
          this.setState({devices: data.member})
          console.log('Devices',this.state.devices)
        })
        .catch(function (error){
          console.log('Error of Axios', error);
        })
    }
    render(){
      return(
        <ul>
        {this.state.devices.map(device => <li>{device.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      );
    }

}

export default Devices;
```

Everything works fine except for the **render()** method which caught the following error:
**'Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'**

> *As I know, if I wanted to compile my code with Reactjs, I meant without Typescript, the aforementioned code should be worked well but
>   how can I define a property (Props in React) without violating TS
>   conventions?*

Note: I searched and found the same questions but their solutions could not solve the issue.

Comment: It's unclear from the question what exactly `data` is. If `device` is supposed to be an object with `name` property, why did you define it as `string`?

Comment: @estus data is an optional name for fetching the received data! I think sth goes wrong, that one is 'devices', I didn't declare any 'device' name.

Comment: Please, specify what exactly `data.member` is equal to. You have a contradiction. In one place you expect `device` to be a string. In another place you expect it to be an object. The compiler just points at it. *I didn't declare any 'device' name* - why is `device.name` in the code then?

Comment: There is no contradiction. `data` is a returned JSON and `member` is one of its elements bounded to `data.element`. By the way, as I mentioned I don't have any problems with receiving data ( I checked by the console.log). The problem is how to map the received data via TS. About your last question why is `device.name` in the code, because of accessing to the `name` property of the device. forget device u can change it to `x` like: `x => {x.name}`.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: It should be clear what the problem is, `State.devices` is declared to be an array of strings. You're mapping those devices attempting to access the `name` property of those strings (as the error message explains). It doesn't matter whether or not what the actual object instance has. Change the definition of your `State` or change the way you map the devices.

Comment: @JeffMercado The question is, How to implement `.map()` in Reactjs and TS based on [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
Please take a look at Get Request, [link](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react)

Comment: You already implemented `map` correctly. These are types that are wrong. There is a contradiction. Otherwise you wouldn't get compiler error. You can trust TS compiler in what it's doing. Posting `data` would help to provide all necessary information in the question unambiguously. I've tried to explain the problem in the the answer.

Comment: @estus Tnq, when I said there is no contradiction, I meant, I can choose an arbitrary name for accessing to elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is compiler error. If the code is working, this means that types were specified incorrectly, and this was detected by TypeScript compiler.

`this.state.devices` is typed to be an array of strings with this line:

```
devices: string[];
```

The compiler expects that `device` is a string at this line, `string` type is inferred because `devices` was typed to be an array of strings:

```
this.state.devices.map(device => <li>{device.name}</li>);
```

While `device` is clearly used as an object and is expected to have `name` property. If `device` is really an object then types should be fixed:

```
export interface State{
  devices: Array<{ name: string }>;
  currentUrl: string;
}
```